# How to fetch parent POM from remote repository

Tags: maven

So I have a corporate repository and there I have the master POM which is already deployed. Now I have other projects which I need to install separately but they have the parent pom .

Whenever I do a mvn clean install , i get unable to find artifact for the parent pom.

My local settings.xml has the mirror defined for central as I assume maven first tries to search for the parent pom in the relativePath, then local repo and at last the remote repo. The parent POM has all the repository and distribution details mentioned so none of these repo infomration is present in the other projects or local settings.xml.

my settings.xml

```
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>nexus3</id>
        <name>my repo</name>
        <url>https://repository.XYZ.com/repository/maven-all/</url>
        <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>

<servers>
    <server>
        <id>nexus3</id>
        <username>userid</username>
        <password>pwd</password>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>nexus3-legacy-releases</id>
        <username>userid</username>
        <password>pwd</password>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>nexus3-legacy-snapshots</id>
        <username>userid</username>
        <password>pwd</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

Pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.xyz.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>xyz-par-pom</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.10-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>ds-sample</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>sample project</name>



<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <reportVersion>2.3.4</reportVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources-filtered</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Error :

```
C:\CodeRepo\xyz-sample>mvn clean install -e -X
Apache Maven 3.6.1 (d66c9c0b3152b2e69ee9bac180bb8fcc8e6af555; 2019-04-05T00:30:29+05:30)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.1\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_202, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
[DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm maven.api
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.annotation.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.annotation.security.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.util.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.classrealm < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.cli < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.exception < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution.scope < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.model < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.monitor < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.plugin < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.profiles < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.project < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.reporting < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.rtinfo < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.settings < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.toolchain < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.usability < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authentication < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.events < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.observers < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.proxy < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.resource < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.component < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.container < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.context < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.logging < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.personality < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParser < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlSerializer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.collection < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.deployment < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.graph < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.installation < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.metadata < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.resolution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.spi < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.transfer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.version < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.fusesource.jansi.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.event.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.helpers.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.spi.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG] Populating class realm maven.api
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Message scheme: color
[DEBUG] Message styles: debug info warning error success failure strong mojo project
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.1\bin\..\conf\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from C:\Users\ach\.m2\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading global toolchains from C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.1\bin\..\conf\toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user toolchains from C:\Users\ach\.m2\toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at C:\Users\ach\.m2\repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Users\ach\.m2\repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata com.xyz.sample:xyz-par-pom:1.1.10-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\ach\.m2\repository)
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.xyz.sample:ds-sample:1.1.10-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.xyz.sample:xyz-par-pom:pom:1.1.10-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 4, column 13
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.xyz.sample:ds-sample:1.1.10-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.xyz.sample:xyz-par-pom:pom:1.1.10-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 4, column 13

    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:395)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.collectProjects (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:414)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.getProjectsForMavenReactor (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:405)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.build (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:82)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.buildGraph (DefaultMaven.java:507)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:219)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project com.xyz.sample:ds-sample:1.1.10-SNAPSHOT (C:\CodeRepo\xyz-sample\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.xyz.sample:ds-sample:1.1.10-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.xyz.sample:xyz-par-pom:pom:1.1.10-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 4, column 13 -> [Help 2]
org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Could not find artifact com.xyz.sample:xyz-par-pom:pom:1.1.10-SNAPSHOT
    at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel (ProjectModelResolver.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel (ProjectModelResolver.java:242)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally (DefaultModelBuilder.java:1062)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent (DefaultModelBuilder.java:838)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build (DefaultModelBuilder.java:332)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:446)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:412)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:375)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.collectProjects (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:414)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.getProjectsForMavenReactor (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:405)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.build (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:82)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.buildGraph (DefaultMaven.java:507)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:219)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact com.xyz.sample:xyz-par-pom:pom:1.1.10-SNAPSHOT
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:257)
    at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel (ProjectModelResolver.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel (ProjectModelResolver.java:242)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally (DefaultModelBuilder.java:1062)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent (DefaultModelBuilder.java:838)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build (DefaultModelBuilder.java:332)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:446)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:412)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:375)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.collectProjects (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:414)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.getProjectsForMavenReactor (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:405)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.build (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:82)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.buildGraph (DefaultMaven.java:507)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:219)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact com.xyz.sample:xyz-par-pom:pom:1.1.10-SNAPSHOT
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact (DefaultArtifactResolver.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:257)
    at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel (ProjectModelResolver.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel (ProjectModelResolver.java:242)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally (DefaultModelBuilder.java:1062)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent (DefaultModelBuilder.java:838)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build (DefaultModelBuilder.java:332)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:446)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:412)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:375)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.collectProjects (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:414)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.getProjectsForMavenReactor (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:405)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.build (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:82)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.buildGraph (DefaultMaven.java:507)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:219)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

Comment: Do you really mean "parent pom as _dependency_"? Because it does not make sense to put a parent POM into the dependency section of your POM.

Comment: not as a dependency but as Parent

Comment: Please post your `pom.xml` and the `mvn clean install -e -X` log. It also often helps to clean the local repository (only for the parent artifact). Sometimes Maven caches 404 for an artifact and does not try to download again.

Comment: I have added the pom and the error into the post

Comment: It looks like Maven is not even trying to reach any other repository than local. In my settings.xml, I have a `<repositories>` element to define the "central" repository.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I solved it by enabling snapshots in pom.xml configuration (although the default should be true):

```
<!-- Artifacts download location -->
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>remote-repo</id> <!-- as in settings.xml -->
        <url>http://myurl-for-group-content</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Without the above configuration, it also worked using a released version (not a SNAPSHOT) for the parent pom.